# Batch Script move file to another folder when delete it

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have some questions to ask you about Batch Script on windows.

I have been share one folder from my computer on network to use Quick book file . i worry about my staff delete Quick book file from this folder.I use Xcopy function in batch file but it just copy.

My Questions:

1- What code do i use for solve this problem? I want to move file that delete to another folder when my staff delete it and i want to record who delete this file.

2- How to run batch file automatically when my staff click delete file?

Thank You For Your Answering.

Note:

- share: i add everyone in share property and i give permission to everyone can read and write.
- Folder Location is D:\QuickBooK

Comment: Do I understand correctly that when another user on the network deletes the shared file, you want things for that user to look as if she deleted the file (the file disappears from the folder) but in fact the file should be moved and the name of that user be recorded?

Comment: I think you should better explain what goal you want to achieve. Why don't you for example just disallow write access? Or why not use a link instead of the file itself, so that when the user attempts to delete the file in fact only the link gets deleted and the file itself stays where it stayed (could be in another directory unreachable from the network).

Comment: Dear Mr Alexander Gelbukh,
i would like to tell you about process this problem. Quick book file that i share to them for entry data. this Quick book file allowance multi user but i must share this folder to read and write file. so this folder will be can read file and write file and can be move and delete also.... so that why i need to do like that. Nowadays i use Xcopy Function to Backup this folder.

Comment: Take a look on TechNet article [Permissions for files and folders](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787794.aspx) of Microsoft. NTFS permissions make it possible that users can read and edit a file, but not delete a file or completely overwrite it with a new file. So it would be perhaps enough to fine tune the NTFS permissions for that folder using advanced NTFS permissions.